# Identify sequences of events starting at well-known start locations, end locations not predetermined, and WITH MYSQL 5.x

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working within the limitations of MySQL 5.x.

Several security guards are responsible to walk around a property and visit checkpoints. Two specific gates permit entry and each guard must begin a "round" at one of the two gates. Each guard can end a "round" at any of the checkpoints for any reason (could be lunch, bathroom stop, paid break, quitting time, etc.). Regrettably there's no device available to definitively record the exact end of a round when it happens.  For that reason, the beginning of a new round is defined by a guard entering again through one of the two known entry gates -- and the end of the previous round is determined "retroactively" to be the last checkpoint visited before the start of the new round.

Guards have unique IDs and can overlap in the time that they're working on the property.

I want to find the "rounds" performed by each guard. In the future, I most probably will wish to analyze the sequence of checkpoints taken during each round, but right now I only want to identify the "exit point" (the last checkpoint visited) of each sequence for each guard.

I prefer to review a list of "rounds" (ordered by guards) with their exit checkpoints, and I would also definitely like to see a histogram of "exit" checkpoints used by all the guards (for example, "is there a specific checkpoint or checkpoints where many guards are habitually choosing to end their rounds?")

The following example data is meant to be for conceptual illustration (for example the date-time information would normally have more precision). The entry gates are designated as locations 17 and 18.

```
 date-time        | guard  | location 
 ----             | ------ | -------- 
 2023-08-02 12:01 | a      | 17         
 2023-08-02 12:01 | b      | 18       
 2023-08-02 12:05 | b      | 20       
 2023-08-02 12:05 | b      | 31       
 2023-08-02 12:06 | b      | 16       
 2023-08-02 12:07 | a      | 11         
 2023-08-02 12:08 | a      | 51         
 2023-08-02 12:08 | b      | 40         
 2023-08-02 12:08 | a      | 56
 2023-08-02 12:18 | b      | 18
 2023-08-02 12:19 | a      | 43         
 2023-08-02 12:19 | c      | 18 
 2023-08-02 12:20 | a      | 17
 2023-08-02 12:21 | b      | 52
 2023-08-02 13:10 | b      | 17
```

The report of "rounds" I'd like to produce, given the example data, would show the following information (regardless of formatting details):

```
Guard a
Round start time  | Round exit checkpiont
2023-08-02 12:01  | 43
2023-08-02 12:20  | (open)

Guard b
Round start time  | Round exit checkpiont
2023-08-02 12:01  | 40
2023-08-02 12:18  | 52
2023-08-02 13:10  | (open)

Guard c
Round start time  | Round exit checkpiont
2023-08-02 12:19  | (open)
```

And it's not really interesting to create a histogram for this tiny amount of data but suffice to say a histogram would include the exit points 43, 40, and 52 (and others).

While straightforward to accomplish the desired reporting with procedural code, it seems I'm not advanced enough to understand how to do this with SQL queries, maybe especially when working within limitations of MySQL 5.x.

First and foremost, I would like to learn a readable and understandable solution, and as second priority I care about efficiency of the solution in terms of time and compute resources.  (Efficiency is good, but not if the efficient solution requires very large amounts of complexity or "mystery" in the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn it into a "groupwise-max" problem.  (See tag I added, but avoid any "CTE solutions; they won't work in 5.7.)

Plan A (just SQL):

1. Find the latest start for the guard (latest date; ckpt IN 17,18) using groupwise-max/
2. Find the last ckpt for that user (order by, limit 1)

Plan B == Application processing needed as the `INSERT` is being done)

- Keep your exising table as a `History` of the details of all "rounds" taken.
- Have another table (`Current`) of exactly the data you want (`guard_id`, `start_time`, `ckpt`).
- When a non-start record (not 17,18) arrives, update `Current.ckpt` of the latest row for that guard.
- When a start record (17 or 18) arrives, `INSERT INTO History VALUES ($guard, NOW(), NULL)`.  This will leave the previous row (for $guard) with the "last" ckpt they stopped at.

You could keep your `History` table so that you have the full paths taken.

This 2-table design pattern is a variant of "History/Current" pattern.  `History` (the table you described) keeps the details; it is write-only.  My `Current` gets updated.  It has one row per "round" that a guard makes.  That is, it keeps track of where each guard was last 'seen'.

Here's my take on [*Groupwise-Max*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

As for efficiency, either Plan will easily handle a million rows, especially if you use an algorithm in my link.  With suitable `PRIMARY KEYs` and `INDEXes`, Plan B might still be "fast enough" with a billion rows in `History`.

Tentatively:

```
History:
    PRIMARY KEY(guard_id, datetime) -- assuming no dup times
Current:
    PRIMARY KEY(guard_id, start_time)

SELECT ckpt,
       COUNT(*) AS 'frequency'
    FROM Current
    GROUP BY ckpt;
```

Comment: I'm encouraged by your reply but at my first reading your Plan A seems to report on the one single "most recent" round completed by each guard.  The problem I'm trying to solve is reporting the start-time and exit point for ALL rounds completed by each guard; for example looking to my question you can see the report outputs two completed rounds with two different start-time/exit checkpoints for "guard b".  Start-times seem easy to find but the corresponding exit points seem trickier (to me!)

Comment: @Newbuntudude - groupwise-max can find the last for each round; finding the groupwise-min to find the data for each.  Then, put the two together.  Tricky, but possible.